# How to allow set hours and minutes for date format?

Tags: jhipster

How to add possibility of set hours and minutes? Currently, I have something like this: 
[image]

But in this case is impossible to set hours and minutes. What should I do to allow set this data via the web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your entity, I suspect the `startDate` field is a `LocalDate`. Try `ZonedDateTime` instead.

```
LocalDate: A java.time.LocalDate object, used to correctly manage dates in Java.
ZonedDateTime: A java.time.ZonedDateTime object, used to correctly manage dates and times in Java.
```

See [creating an entity](https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/).